# Must user provided terminate() function be thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, terminate-handler

As stated in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate there are many reasons to call terminate. I can imagine case where just almost in the same time some of these reasons happen in two threads.

**Q1** Can the terminate function set by `std::set_terminate` be called twice or more at the same time, by the same time I mean second call begins before first has ended.

```
  Thread1   Thread2
    |          |
    _          |
    t          |
    e          |
    r          |
    m          |
    i          _
    n          t
    a          e
    t          r
    e          m
    -          ?
```

**Q2** If Q1==YES, then what happens if first terminate ended. I guess if it ended with std::abort, then program ends, but what happens if user provided terminate does not abort program?

**Q3** Is the terminate function set by `std::set_terminate` called in context of the thread which caused this terminate call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Q1**

Yes, `std::terminate` can be called concurrently.

**Q2**

The standard says it is undefined behavior for a `terminate_handler` to not "terminate execution of the program without returning to the caller".  In implementations I'm familiar with, if the `terminate_handler` attempts to return, either normally, or exceptionally, `abort()` will be called.

**Q3**

The function set by `std::terminate` is a global, not a thread local.  So one thread can impact another.

In C++98/03, the `terminate_handler` used when `terminate` is called due to an uncaught exception is the one that was in effect when the exception was thrown, not the one in effect when `terminate` is actually called (though they are usually the same).

In C++11 this was changed and the standard now says that the handler used is the one in place at the time `terminate` is called.  This change was done by mistake and will most likely be corrected in a future draft.  Here is the LWG issue tracking this issue:

http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-active.html#2111

**Update**

At the Spring 2015 meeting in Lenexa, KS, the LWG decided to standardize existing behavior and made it unspecified when a new `terminate_handler` goes into effect if `set_terminate` is called during stack unwinding.  I.e. implementations are allowed to follow either the C++98/03 rules or the C++11 rules.

To make your code portable, if you need to set a `terminate_handler`, do so during program startup, before any exceptions will be thrown, and do not make a habit of calling `set_terminate` after that.

Comment: +1. Just to answer question in subject: user provided terminate function must be thread safe? What about other "on disaster" functions? What about new_handler? Is this gcc advice dangerous of being double delete: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/dynamic_memory.html?

Comment: Since `std::terminate` can be called concurrently, the `terminate_handler` should be thread safe.  And the same is true of all other handlers specified in the standard, including `new_handler`.  Yes, the gcc example is in danger of performing a double delete.  This could be solved with an atomic exchange on `safety`.

Comment: "function set by std::set_terminate is a global" - Why? Some implementations says it is local ([ms:terminate functions are maintained separately for each thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272914(v=vs.60).aspx); [ibm:You can override this with a thread-level termination](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.bpxbd00/setterm.htm);[sun:thread can set its own](http://www.amath.unc.edu/sysadmin/DOC4.0/c-plusplus/c%2B%2B_ug/Exception_Handling.doc.html)) Can't find exact definition in the standard.http://stackoverflow.com/q/15367060/196561