# C++, is set_terminate local to every thread?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, language-lawyer, c++03

Should `set_terminate`/`get_terminate` set a different terminate exception processor for several threads in C++ 2011 or C++ 2003?

E.g. if I have program and sets terminate handler to `func_1`; then I start 3 threads. What are terminate handlers in new threads? What if in every thread I will set terminate handler to `func_2` in first thread, `func_3` in second thread and so on.

[N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) (C++ 2011 draft) says nothing about it in `[handler.functions]` or in `[support.exception]`/`[exception.terminate]`

PS: You may answer for C++2011 or for C++2003 of for any popular implementation of these standards

PPS: There is FCD Comment for this... [C++ FCD Comment Status Rev. 5 N3249 (2011)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3249.html):

```
GB 71    18.6.2.4 / 18.8.2.2 / 18.8.3.2
```

> The thread safety of `std::set_new_handler()`, `std::set_unexpected()`, `std::set_terminate()`, is unspecified making the the functions impossible to use in a thread safe manner.
>
> The thread safety guarantees for the functions must be specified and new interfaces should be provided to make it possible to query and install handlers in a thread safe way.
>
> LWG   [1365](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-toc.html#1365)    ACCEPTED with MODIFICATIONS
>
> See paper  [N3189](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3189.htm)

Comment: DR1365 was resolved prior to issuing C++11, by adopting the language on data races quoted in my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

17.6.4.7p4 says:

> Calling the `set_*` and `get_*` functions shall not incur a data race. A call to any of the `set_*` functions shall synchronize with subsequent calls to the same `set_*` function and to the corresponding `get_*` function.

This strongly implies that the `set_*` and `get_*` functions are operating on the same global state even when called from different threads.  All the paragraphs under 18.8.3 discuss "*the current handler function*", with no other mention of threading; this indicates that the handler function is a property of the program as a whole; similarly, 17.6.4.7 has:

> 2 - A C++ program may install different handler functions during execution [...]
>   3 - A C++ program can get a pointer to the current handler function by calling the following functions [...]

These paragraphs discuss *the current handler function* in the context of a program, indicating that it is program-scope and not thread-local.

Comment: When set_* and get_* works on thread-local state, there will be no data race too. And there are at least 3 implementation with documented thread-local state: ms, ibm, sun.

Comment: There are MS VS 6 and SUN (smth old): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272914(v=vs.60).aspx & http://www.amath.unc.edu/sysadmin/DOC4.0/c-plusplus/c%2B%2B_ug/Exception_Handling.doc.html; both says about thread-local `terminate`: ms: "In a multithreaded environment, terminate functions are maintained separately for each thread."; sun: "Each thread can set its own terminate() or unexpected() function. Calling set_terminate() or set_unexpected() in one thread affects only the exceptions in that thread.". Are they wrong?

Comment: @osgx the MS documentation is discussing a C library function in `<eh.h>`; the C++ library function is documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241196(v=vs.60).aspx.  The Sun documentation is as you say very old; prior to C++11 C++ did not consider threads so having thread-local terminate handlers would be a conforming extension.

Comment: A link to the most recent MSDN page for the  `<eh.h>` `set_terminate()` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6fk7h29.aspx (so things don't get sidetracked by a 15 year old implementation). While this function is part of the C runtime, the docs say "set_terminate is used with C++ exception handling...", so it might be that the C++ runtime uses it to implement its `set_terminate()` from `<exception>`. On the other hand, the MSDN docs for `set_terminate()` in `<exception>` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ycf93beb.aspx - don't mention threads.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6fk7h29.aspx for Visual Studio 2013 very clearly states "In a multithreaded environment, terminate functions are maintained separately for each thread. Each new thread needs to install its own terminate function. Thus, each thread is in charge of its own termination handling."

Answer (score 4):

In the Standard it says under

**18.8.3.2 set_terminate [set.terminate]**

`terminate_handler set_terminate(terminate_handler f) noexcept;`

> 1 Effects: Establishes the function designated by f as the current handler function for **terminating** exception processing.

`[[noreturn]] void terminate() noexcept;`

> 2 Effects: Calls the current terminate_handler function. [ Note: A default terminate_handler is **always considered** a callable handler in this context. —end note ]

You can see that `terminate()`  calls the **current** terminate handler, which in the `set_handler` section it quite clearly says it is used for **terminating** a process.  This gets called when all other exception handling has failed, irrespective from which thread is running.

There is only one terminate handler, and it always gets called from wherever the program is terminating.

Comment: [IBM says](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/topic/com.ibm.zos.r11.bpxbd00/setterm.htm): "You can override this with a thread-level termination by supplying a function which invokes pthread_exit() as a terminate function. This terminates the thread but not the process."

Comment: And... terminating of "exception processing" means not the terminating of process. Single thread can be terminated too.

Comment: But that is the global terminate handler refering to the thread it was called from (by calling `pthread_exit`), not a thread-specific handler.

Comment: @osgx `pthread_exit` is still a program-scope terminate handler in that case; IBM is just providing an extension to allow the terminate handler to terminate only the thread.

Answer (score 4):

The standard doesn't exactly specify; [[set.terminate]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/exception.terminate) states only

> [...] the current handler function for terminating exception processing.

but doesn't mention if "current" is global or per-thread. So it depends on the implementation.

For example, in MSVC++:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6fk7h29.aspx

> In a multithreaded environment, terminate functions are maintained separately for each thread. Each new thread needs to install its own terminate function. Thus, each thread is in charge of its own termination handling.

Answer (score 1):

C2003 has no threads, any thread support is a vendor extension so only vendor-supplied documentation has the answer. If the handler is per thread, the documentation ought to say that. No implementation I know does it.

C++2011 says nothing about per-thread nature of the terminate handler. It would make little sense to maintain it per thread, because you cannot kill a thread in C++11. And for a good reason too (google kill+thread+c++11). So whatever you do, the program must terminate. It looks like having different ways to terminate the program depending on the thread that requested it is not a feature anyone needs.

Comment: Sun/Oracle did/does thread-local `set_terminate`: [Solaris Studio 12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1383/bkaid.html#indexterm-258) "Each thread can set its own terminate() or unexpected() function. Calling set_terminate() or set_unexpected() in one thread affects only the exceptions in that thread. "

Comment: It is thread-specific in MSVC as well.  Different threads are started for different reasons, by different regions of your code, or indeed by 3rd-party libraries.  It is reasonable to want to do some thread-specific activity prior terminating the process.